# Why does my if statement doesn't repeat when the condition is met?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a typing speed test and hope when I click space (`on_space` function) that I could check the user's input with the word list and also delete the typed words in the word list. However, I'm having trouble that the checking and deleting condition is not looping rather than stopping after the 1st word. The issue either be the variable wpm (the word per minute) is not defined when execute at the time the countdown stop or the wpm is always 1, which retains the 1st value typed.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import csv
import sys
import time


window = Tk()

# setting tkinter window size
window.state("zoomed")
window.update_idletasks()
window.configure(bg="gray")

window.title("Typing Test")

# opens csv file and converts to list for data management
with open("typingwords.csv", "r") as read_obj:  # read csv file as a list of lists
    csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj)
    wordList = list(csv_reader)
    # Randomizes the list and splices it to only have 150 words
    random.shuffle(wordList)
    splicedlist = wordList[:150]

# displays the words
fontTuple = ("Playfair Display", 16, "bold")
x1 = Label(window, text=splicedlist, wraplength=1100, fg="white")
x1.config(bg="gray")
x1.config(font=fontTuple)
x1.pack(ipadx=500, ipady=20)


# defines the function used to delete the inside of entry after every space
typedValue = []

def on_space(e1):
    global typedValue
    global wpm
    x = " ".join(splicedlist.pop(0))  # after the word is being typed
    if e1.widget.get() != x:
        e1.widget.delete(0, "end")
        x1.config(text=splicedlist)
        pass
    else:
        typedValue.append(x)
        wpm = len(typedValue)
        print(wpm)
        e1.widget.delete(0, "end")
        x1.config(text=splicedlist)
# Timer
sec = int(60)
time = str(f"00:{sec}")
c1 = Label(window, text=time, wraplength=500, fg="white")
c1.config(bg="gray")
c1.config(font=fontTuple)
c1.pack(ipadx=500, ipady=200)


def countdown(count):
    if count > 0:
        window.after(1000, countdown, count - 1)
        c1.config(text=count)
    if count == 0:
        sys.exit(f"Time's Up! Your words per minute is {wpm}")


fontTuple = ("Playfair Display", 16, "bold")
e1 = Entry(window)
e1.config(font=fontTuple)
e1.bind("<space>", on_space)
e1.bind("<Button-1>", countdown(60))
e1.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're calling `countdown(60)` when you bind the button, not when you click the button. That should be `lambda: countdown(60)`

Comment: There's a problem with `x = " ".join(splicedlist.pop(0))`.  The `pop` is going to return one word.  The `join` is then going to join the letters, like `"w o r d"`.  If you have one word, you don't really want to `join` it.

Comment: @Barmar: that needs to be `lambda event: countdown(60)`